# R Studio - change data type from numeric into text

Tags: rstudio

i'm newbie in R studio and R language. and I hope all of you can give me a clue or enlightenment.

I have field on my database (i'm using MySQL) , data type of that field was text (I need this data type for my record), the example record that I put on that field is :

123456789012345

so when I select the record from my table, it will look like this :

details

123456789012345

but when I tried to read the data in rstudio (i'm using rodbc package for accesing my database), i'm using simple query, just select the field from the table, but the ouput from rstudio was :

details

1 1.234567e+14

I've tried using str() function and convert it to char, but nothing works.

cpuld anyone help me to solved my issue, so the output can be :

123456789012345

many thanks.

regards,

bambang

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps... You can use as.character to convert numeric to character datatype

`test1=123456789012345

class(test1)

[1] "numeric"

as.character(test1)

[1] "123456789012345"`